# 403 Error for Custom Login Page Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am getting a 403 error whenever I try to login in to the home page of my spring boot application using Spring Security. The login does not throw an 403 error whenever I use spring security's default login page.

https://prnt.sc/svxyc8

Below is my configure method.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
{
    http.authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/css/**").permitAll()
    .antMatchers().hasAnyRole("ADMIN","USER")
    .antMatchers("/").permitAll().and().formLogin().loginPage("/login");
}
```

Below is a picture of my file structure:

http://prntscr.com/svy9ly

Below is my Controller.

```
@Controller
public class AuthenticationController 
{
    /*
      Get request to allow us to see the login page. This page is
      stores in the static folder.
     */
    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String login()
    {
        return "login";
    }

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String index()
    {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

Database Structure: http://prntscr.com/svya5d

login.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="www.thymeleaf.org">
    <!-- We need ThymeLeaf. This provides a rendering engine to allow Spring boot to know that there are templates for it to render -->
    <head>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form method="POST">
                <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="name">Username</div>
                        <div class="value">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                        <input class="input--style-5" type="text" name="userID">
                                </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="name">Password</div>
                        <div class="value">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                        <input class="input--style-5" type="password" name="userPW">
                                </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                        <button class="btn btn--radius-2 btn--red" type="submit">Login</button>
                </div>
                <a class="myLinkLog" href="register">Create an account</a>
        </form>
</html>
```

Comment: Why do you have `http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(new Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint());` ? Can you show your `login.html` code?

Comment: @WimDeblauwe that shouldn't be there sorry. I will update it now and also add login.html.

Comment: Added login.html.

Comment: Your login page should be "/login" and you should add `.antMatchers("/login").permitAll()`

Comment: @AndreiStoicescu I still get the same error when I add that in. It works perfectly with the spring security default login page, so it definitely could not be an issue with my database.

Comment: I would add "/error" endpoint to your security configuration (sth like: .antMatchers("/css/**").permitAll()).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set a form action and use the proper input names. This is a minimal example:

```
        <form th:action="@{/login}" method="post">

            <input type="text" name="username" />
            <input type="password" name="password" />

            <button type="submit" th:text="#{login}"></button>
        </form>
```

Comment: Hey I added the `<form th:action="@{/login}" method="post">`, that got it to work thanks. The last part `<button type="submit" th:text="#{login}"></button>` made the text on my button look weird. What is the purpose of `th:text="#{login}"`?

Comment: That allows to translate texts. If you don't need i18n support in your application, you can remove that and use `<button type="submit">Login</button>`. If you want to use it, add a `src/main/resources/messages.properties` file and add `login=Login`.

Comment: Thanks very much! I've been stuck on this for a day.